# Convert array of embedded documents into array of elements in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

What is the query or aggregation operator I can use to get this ?

### Input:

```
{"_id": "id1", "contacts": [{"phone": "xxx", "email":"id1@gmail.com"}, {"phone":"yyy"}, {"phone":"zzz", "email":"id1_1@gmail.com"}] }
{"_id": "id2", "contacts": [{"phone": "aaa", "email":"id2@gmail.com"}, {"phone":"bbb"}, {"phone":"ccc"}] }
```

### Output:

(just need phone numbers, other contacts.fields can be dropped)

```
{"_id": "id1", "contacts": ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"] }
{"_id": "id2", "contacts": ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) aggregation pipeline stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "contacts": "$contacts.phone"
    }
  }
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZpkkPSGS_D0)

```
[
  { "_id": "id1", "contacts": [ "xxx", "yyy", "zzz" ] },
  { "_id": "id2", "contacts": [ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" ] }
]
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony. Sorry, just need little more, how do I get unique values into array? Seems some of Ids have duplicate phone numbers in collection.

Comment: You can use `$setUnion` aggregation for that

Comment: @Nar If you need any help in that then please ask a new question i will help you